# Möbius transformation taking line segment between two complex numbers to the segment $[-1,1]$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, mobius-transformation, complex-manifolds

I am reading Kodaira's *Complex Analysis*, and trying to understand his proof of the uniformization theorem for simply connected Riemann surfaces. Due to what I assume is translation errors, this book (though very excellent) has many misprints. I have spent several hours trying to figure out what Kodaira actually meant in the following (page 331; Chapter 7 section 1, in the paragraph immediately preceding the statement of theorem 7.4):

> If $F$ is the segment connecting $\alpha$ and $\beta = \alpha + \delta$, $\delta > 0$, the transformation $w \rightarrow 2/\delta(w - (\alpha + \beta)/z)$ carries $F$ into the segment $[-1,1]$.

The problem I'm having is that the transformation he gives *doesn't* take $F$ to that segment at all. Also, there is a $z$ in my edition that I can only assume was supposed to be a $2$. I tried messing around with linear fractional transformations to derive the formula myself with no luck, as I am left with one degree of freedom (which leads me to also consider the possibility that the $z$ is in fact supposed to be a $z$).

Here is what I tried:

Since we're considering biholomorphic maps on the Riemann sphere, the transformation we want will be a Möbius transformation of the form
$$f(w) = \frac{aw + b}{cw + d}.$$

We want $f(\alpha) = -1$, $f(\beta) = 1$, and points of the form $\alpha +  t \delta$ (for $t \in [0,1]$) to lie in the interval $[-1, 1]$. This gives us the equations:

$$a\alpha + b = c\alpha + d\\
a\beta + b = -c\beta - d$$

If we let $(\alpha + \beta)/2 \mapsto 0$, we get an additional equation, except with this relation we get $c = 0$ which to me seems very wrong:

$$a(\alpha + \beta)/2 + b = 0\\
\implies a(\alpha + \beta) + 2b = 0$$

Hence,
$$a \alpha + a \beta + 2b = c (\alpha - \beta) = 0 \implies c = 0$$
So $f(w) = (a/d) w + b/d$.

I'm hoping someone with more expertise on the matter can help me figure this out. I'm sure I'm either doing something wrong, or there's something trivial here I'm missing. Thanks.

EDIT: The $z$ in the expression is indeed supposed to be a $2$. After the wonderful observation of Izaak below, it turns out I foolishly assumed the division symbol was suppose to carry over the entire expression. That is, $$f(w) = \frac{2}{\delta(w - (\alpha + \beta)/2)}.$$ This is *not* the case. The expression is to be interpreted as $\frac{2}{\delta}(w - (\alpha + \beta)/2)$. I might as well carry through the derivation above (in fact, getting $c = 0$ was the correct result).

If $f(w) = (a/d) w + b/d$, then knowing that $f(\alpha) = -1$ and $f(\beta) = 1$, we get:
$$a\alpha + b - d = 0\\
a \beta + b + d = 0$$
which we can solve as a system of linear equations to get:
$$a = -\frac{2}{\delta} t\\
b = \frac{\alpha + \beta}{\delta} t\\
d = t$$
where we may choose $t$ however we like. To get the expression Kodaira uses, choose $t = -1$. We get $a = 2/\delta$, and $b = -\frac{\alpha + \beta}{\delta} = -\frac{2}{\delta}\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}$

Comment: Are you sure the given transformation is wrong? I think it's supposed to be interpreted as $w \mapsto \tfrac 2\delta (w - \tfrac 12(\alpha + \beta))$. This maps $\alpha$ to $-1$, $\beta$ to $1$, and $\tfrac 12 (\alpha + \beta)$ to $0$. So by general "preserving circles on the Riemann sphere" properties, it must have the claimed property. (But also, really, it just rotates and scales the line segment in the way you want). You're right that there's a degree of freedom - you can choose any map that sends $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ to $\{1,-1\}$ and $\tfrac 12(\alpha+\beta)$ to any point in $(-1, 1)$.

Comment: Argh! I was interpreting that as $\frac{2}{\delta(w - \frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta))}$. I didn't even think to consider that the division symbol was only supposed to carry over to the $\delta$. I'm such a fool. Thanks.

Comment: One extra thing to keep in mind: for carrying one line segment of the complex plane to another, all you need is a map of the form $f(w)=aw+b$, in other words a similarity transformation of the Euclidean plane. This, of course, was known to Euclid, although we translate into modern language using complex numbers. So all you really have to do is solve the system of equations $a \alpha + b = -1$, $a \beta + b = 1$ for $a$ and $b$.